# How to set up storing period in Amazon Glacier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I've read that Glacier can store documents for "month, years and even decades".
Where or how I can specify how long archive needed to be stored at Amazon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of your quote:

> Amazon Glacier is designed for use cases where data is retained for months, years, or decades. Deleting data from Amazon Glacier is free if the archive being deleted has been stored for three months or longer. If an archive is deleted within three months of being uploaded, you will be charged an early deletion fee.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/

The point here is that glacier is intended for long-term storage, not short-term storage, and that you'll be billed for 3 months minimum if you use glacier outside its intended application.

Glacier doesn't delete things on its own.

Comment: I understand it. But how long documents will be stored at Glacier? Is it sett by account/vault of Amazon will store them forever?

Comment: They will be stored until you delete them.  If you are using the Glacier storage class of S3, they are persisted in Glacier until either you delete them, or a lifecycle policy deletes them.

Answer (score 0):

S3 lifecycle policies.

You can specifiy transitions from one storage class to another, and an expiration date after which objects will be automatically deleted.

Take a look at the documentation for [put-bucket-lifecycle.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle.html)